# How do the higher level skills like Artisan and Agriculturalist work in Multiplayer?

Tags: stardew-valley

In Stardew Valley Multiplayer certain things are shared between players (Farm Space, Money, Shipping Box) while other things are separate (Skills and XP, NPC relationships). I am wondering about the specifics of how the higher level skills work in Multiplayer so that I can make better use of player skills in my 4 player world.

If one person has the skill does it get applied to everyone on the server? Does the player with a value increasing skill need to be the one to drop things in the shipping box, or do they need to be the one to collect/harvest the item?

**How do skills like Artisan (Artisan Goods worth 40% more), Agriculturist (All crops grow 10% faster), or Tracker (Location of Foraged Items revealed) work in multiplayer?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the official release of 1.3.27 I have been doing some experimentation on my current 2 player Farm. I will add more information as results come in, but in terms of what I have gathered so far...

**Price Raising Skills from *levels* (eg. [Artisan](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Skills#Farming)): Shared**
When items are dropped in the shipping box, it applies the bonus as long as at least one person on the server has Artisan (+40% value to Artisan Goods) regardless of who drops it into the box.
[image: Shipment-box Jelly]
Here I (with Artisan) created and dropped into the shipping box the Apple Jelly, while the host (with Agriculturalist) created and dropped in the Orange Jelly. Both has the +40% value applied. The Shipping box we used was the one that comes with the farm.

**Price Raising Items: Individual**

> When I obtained the [Bear's Knowledge](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Bear%27s_Knowledge), my Blackberries and Salmonberries had the 3x price raise applied but berries sold by my Host partner without still sold for berries for regular price (even if I was the one who picked the berries).

**[Botanist](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Foraging#Foraging_Skill): Individual**
Once getting Botanist, only the forage that I pick-up is Iridium Quality. Forage picked-up by my host partner has the regular spread of quality.

**[Agricultrist](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Skills#Farming): Individual**
The rate at which the crops grow is dependent on who plants them. In the images below the Crops on the left are planted by The Host (with Agriculturist) and the crops on the right are planted by me (Artisan). All Cauliflower were planted on
Day 1 of Spring.
*Day 9 Harvest(Agriculturist plus Deluxe Speed-Gro):*
[image: Day9]

*Day 10 Harvest(Artisan plus Deluxe Speed-Gro):*
[image: Day 10]

*Day 11 Harvest(Agriculturist):*
[image: Day11]

*Day 13 Harvest(Artisan):*
[image: Day13]

I am not sure how having multiple professions will stack, but I plan on testing this once we get a bit more cash and xp on our farm.

> Once we both hit max level in the different skills, and have lots of cash floating around, testing should be easy with the Re-spec statue.

Comment: A Reddit user has provided some insight glean from source code, will include into answer when I have more time. [Professions in Multiplayer (and the Speed-Gro Bug)](https://old.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/975gl9/professions_in_multiplayer_and_the_speedgro_bug/)

Comment: @Malco are you going to add that info into your answer? If not it would be nice if you cleaned up your comment and flag mine after :)

Comment: @Akixkisu Ended up switching to another game with my Stardew Partner so never got a chance to finish testing. There has been several significant updates since this was originally posted so would probably need to be tested again from the beginning to see if things still work this way. I will leave the comment with the reddit post as it has some useful info but isn't really part of my answer. Thanks for the interest tho.

Comment: This answer as written holds true as of 1.5.3 Though I would add that for each item placed in any shipping bin (there are now more than one variant), the price is determined by the *online* player whose professions would most increase it, and that for each item sold to an NPC only that player's professions apply. :)

Comment: For Splitscreen multiplayer this also holds true (online would be active here).

Answer (score 4):

For price increasing skills, if items are sold using the box, the host's skill bonuses apply. Other players' skills do not apply. If players sell an item to a vendor, such as crops to Pierre or fish to Willy, that player's skills apply.

This means if you have the artisan skill and the host doesn't, you should make sure you sell those goods yourself to get the best value.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/8go1op/psa_in_multiplayer_extra_profit_skills_only_count/

Comment: After a bit of research/playing the game it seems like this might not be true anymore.... I will have clearer proof once I hit 10 farming in my mp game